# How should be storage_path in simple-youtube-api?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to make a program that will be uploaded automate video on youtube.
I found a python library on the internet:  `simple-youtube-api`
But I don't understand how to send authentication information (login, password).
I found `storage_path` in the function method, but I don't understand how to put the correct information in that path

```
from simple_youtube_api.Channel import Channel

# loggin into the channel
channel = Channel()
channel.login("client_secret_json", "storage_path" )
```

Can someone tell me how should be correct information in `storage_path` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create an empty file and put its name as a value in storage_path, it will populated automatically after your first run with the appropriate token.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: listen here u little s***, my answer is clear, precise, and to the point, go train harder